# Forward and Inverse Kinematics for robot MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics, inverse-kinematics, kinematics

Hope you are doing well.

I am verifying the output of my forward kinematics through inverse kinematics and the results are not as desired. As the output of my inverse kinematics is not coming out to be the same as the input of forward kinematics.

The D-H parameters of manipulator is given as:

Link: alpha, a, theta, d

Link 1 :         -90            0        theta1*        d1

Link 2 :           0            a2       theta2*         0

Link 3 :           0            a3       theta3*         0

Functions used are:

Inverse kinematics

```
function q = inv_kinematics(ph)
%input in radians: [ph1 ph2 ph3] = [0.1 0.2 0.4]
l1 = 0.05;
l2 = 0.28;
l3 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.03;
ph1 = ph(1);
ph2 = ph(2);
ph3 = ph(3);
r=sqrt(ph1^2+(ph3-d1)^2);
alpha=acos((r^2+l2^2-l3^2)/(2*r*l2))
q = zeros(3,1);
q1=atan2(ph2,ph1);
q2=atan2(ph1,ph3-d1)-alpha;
q3=atan2(ph1-l2*sin(q2),ph3-d1-l2*cos(q2))-q2;
q=[q1;q2;q3];
%output: q = [1.107 -0.265 1.314]
end
```

Forward kinematics:

```
function ph  = forward_kinematics(q)
%input: [q1 q2 q3] = [1.107 -0.265 1.314]
l2 = 0.28;
l3 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.03;
q1 = q(1);
q2 = q(2);
q3 = q(3);
ph = zeros(3,1);
ph1 = l2*cos(q1)*cos(q2)+l3*cos(q1)*cos(q2+q3);
ph2 = l2*sin(q1)*cos(q2)+l3*sin(q1)*cos(q2+q3);
ph3 = d1-l2*sin(q2)-l3*sin(q2+q3);
ph=[ph1;ph2;ph3];
%output: p = [0.1655 0.3308 -0.07005] 
end
```

Comment: Although uploading your code is a good start, you are more likely to get a useful response if you supply a working example, showing what you get and why it isn't correct.

Comment: I am using output of inverse kinematics as input of forward dynamics. The problem is in the 3rd value i.e z-coordinate. The input values that I am using are present in this Simulink file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cH5JLDtkv0vauPBtYDpaCcv2Ba9-4Ek3

Comment: Very few (if any) people here are going to download a random model from someone they don't know.  As part of your question please provide a value for `q` (presumably a 3-element numeric vector) showing what your first function gives for `ph`, and then what your second function gives for `q`.